# Upgrading to MassTransit 7, CreateBrokeredMessageRecevier deprecated

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

Having just upgraded to .NET 6 and updated all NuGet packages in the solution to latest, including MassTransit, it appears that `CreateBrokeredMessageReceiver` is no longer available.

Inside an Azure Function, I have the following code which creates a `BrokeredMessageReceiver` and configured the consumer based on some generics.

What is the alternative approach now that `CreatedBrockeredMessageRecevier` has been removed?

```cs
        [FunctionName("CommandHandler")]
        public async Task HandleCommandAsync(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("%InputQueueName%")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
            IBinder binder,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            ...
                    var handler = Bus.Factory.CreateBrokeredMessageReceiver(
                        binder,
                        cfg =>
                            {
                                cfg.CancellationToken = cancellationToken;
                                cfg.InputAddress = new Uri(
                                    $"{this.settings.Value.ServiceBusUri}/{this.settings.Value.InputQueueName}");
                                if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
                                {
                                    cfg.UseRetry(x => x.Intervals(Consumer<Command>.RetryIntervals));
                                }

                                cfg.Consumer(
                                    GetConsumerType(messageType),
                                    type => this.serviceProvider.GetService(type));
                            });

                    await handler.Handle(message);

                   ...
        }
```

```cs
        private static Type GetConsumerType(string messageType)
        {
            var commandType = typeof(CreateSnippetCommand).Assembly.GetTypes()
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Equals(messageType));
            var consumerType = typeof(IConsumer<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);
            return consumerType;
        }
```

Comment: What version did you upgrade from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look at the [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-AzureFunction/blob/master/src/Sample.AzureFunction/SubmitOrderFunctions.cs) that goes along with the Azure Function support built into MassTransit.

Comment: Thanks, I've replaced the `CreateBrokeredMessageReceiver` with something like: 
`MethodInfo method = typeof(IMessageReceiver).GetMethod("HandleConsumer");

MethodInfo genericHandleMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(consumerType);

genericHandleMethod.Invoke(this.messageReceiver, new object[] { inputQueueName, message, cancellationToken });`

Comment: However I can't invoke the Azure Function now.  It is set up like the example you provided, but when I send a message over the bus, I get `MassTransit.WebJobs.ServiceBusIntegration: A connection string must be used for Azure Functions. (Parameter 'ServiceBus').`

Comment: Ah, fixed it, just needed the second parameter of `AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions`, `connectionStringConfigurationKey`. Although it wasn't in the sample you provided.

Comment: That seems completely insane to me, vs configuring the message receiver through the container. All that reflection stuff seems crazy, sorry. Why are you doing it?

Comment: Because I have a generic consumer like Consumer<T> rather than a concrete consumer per message type. The generic consumer invokes a rule engine which runs rules appropriate for the type of message, so I need to invoke the generic `Consumer<T>` based on the message type.

Comment: Although you are right, it is a bit crazy, so actually I decided to downgrade and go back to `CreateBrokeredMessageReceiver`, at least for the time being.